# CSS Alignment, image and text

Tags: css

I want to put one image left, one image right and text in the middle.

I keep thinking I am close then one or another runs away! I would appreciate some help and guidance.

Code for page and CSS below

VB page

```
<div id="HeaderTitleWrapper">

<h2><img src="images/Header/logo.jpg" alt="Writting Icon" /> 
<div id="HeaderTel"> 
GATEWAY<img src="images/Header/pic2.jpg" alt="Writing Icon" />
&nbsp;</div> <!-- HeaderTel -->
</h2>


</div> <!-- HeaderTitleWrapper -->
```

CSS

```
/* Header Text Title  */


#HeaderTitleWrapper {
  width: 1000px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;

}

#HeaderTitleContent {    
    padding: 0px;    
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top:10px;

}

#HeaderTel 
{

    position:absolute;
    right:150px;
    top:auto;

}
```

Comment: are you looking for some like this : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dlvCp ?

Comment: @GCyrillus never use `*` !!1!1eleven

Comment: @GCyrillus What would you do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using text-align:justify and pseudo , you can spray inline-boxes from left to right.

```
<header>
    <img/>
    <span>text</span>
    <img/
<header>
```

```
header {
   line-height:0;
   text-align:justify;
}
header span {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
   line-height:1.2em;
}
header:after {
   content:'';
   display:inline-block;
   width:99%;
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

similar exemple : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dlvCp

Answer (score 0):

```
<div
id="firstImage">
    <img
    src="1.jpg"
    alt="Writting Icon"
    />
    </div>
    <span
    id="Text">
        GATEWAY
        </span>
        <div
        id="secondImage">
            <img
            src="2.jpg"
            alt="Writing Icon"
            />
            </div>
            <!-- HeaderTel -->
    </div>
```

Comment: So I am close... @gv.neo that works bar the text being centred. Thanks, any clue why text is not centred. #TEXTChange 
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000080;       
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;

}